# Перестали собираться cmake проекты (при кросскомпиляции) после обновления boost до версии 1.70

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, c++17, кросс-компиляция

Решил обновить boost с 1.67 до 1.70. После обновления все cmake скрипты линкующие boost перестали нормально парсится и выдают ошибку:

```
/usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:95: error: 
Found package configuration file: /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_system-1.70.0/boost_system-config.cmake but it set boost_system_FOUND to FALSE so package "boost_system" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  
Reason given by package: No suitable build variant has been found. /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:124 (boost_find_dependency) /usr/local/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:266 (find_package) CMakeLists.txt:73 (find_package)
```

На форумах cmake нашёл соответствующую тему, в которой говорилось что для сборки проектов с новейшим boost нужен новейший cmake и для 70той версии нужна cmake версии 3.14. Запулил, собрал, установил, десктопные проекты стали нормально собираться. Проблема в том, что часть моих проектов используют кросс-компиляцию и собираются под Linux-arm. Собрал 70тый boost под arm, попробовал собрать проект и получил туже ошибку (т.е. обновление до cmake 3.14 в случае кросс-компиляции не помогло).

Часть CMake скрипта ответсвенная за линковку arm boost:

```
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)      # Определяем в каком режиме будет работать boost в статическом или динамическом
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)    # Будет ли boost работать в многопоточном режиме.
set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)  # Говорим что буст нужен не из системной папки
set (BOOST_ROOT "/home/rivandblack/LinaroToolchain/target_lib/boost_1_70_0/") # Говорим откуда необходимо брать boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system) # Находим boost по ссылке BOOST_ROOT (system тут обязательна) 
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}) # Добавляем пути 
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})    # Добавляем пути
```

В cmake скрипте обратите внимание что я подменяю системный путь boost что бы "подсунуть" нужный вариант библиотеки. Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но до этой версии это всегда работало корректно.

На машине на которой собирается arm проект используется Kubuntu 18.04; cmake 3.14.3; GCC 7.3; boost 1.70; IDE Qt Creator 4.9.0.

Comment: сталкивался с такой проблемой. Решать ее не стал - просто откатился к версии 1.69. У нее нет подобной проблемы

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а как откатился? У меня не получается =) В смысле я собираю 69 версию, делаю make install, даже в cmake скрипте явно указываю версию, но cmake всёравно лезет в 70тый скрипты.

Comment: Удалите версию 1.70 а потом ставте  1.69

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а как это сделать на Linux если я устанавливал её через b2?

Comment: следовало пользоваться checkinstall

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а как checkinstall применить к boost? Он же не через make скрипт собирается.

Comment: Для checkinstall не обязателен make - можно указать команду для инсталяции вручную

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Действительно. В общем я собрал дебиановский пакет и через него смог удалить 70тый буст. После этого десктопные приложения стали нормально собираться на 3.12ом (старом) cmake, но с arm всё осталось по-прежнему. Я подумал, что теперь виноват 3.14тый cmake и полностью удалил все cmake’и из системы, после чего установил ванильный из репозитория (т.е. apt install cmake). Проблема осталась. CMake упорно продолжает ссылатся на boost-1.70.0.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Проблема решена. Удалил всё что было в каталоге /usr/local/lib/cmake и всё заработало. Видать при полном удалении cmake этот каталог остаётся нетронутым. Большое спасибо вам за помощь.